# how to write formulas like summation in XSLT template transformation

Tags: java, xslt, xls, xlsx

in my program

```
Map<String, Collection<Employee>> beans = new HashMap<String, Collection<Employee>>();
        beans.put("employee", staff);
        XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();
        try {
            transformer.transformXLS("C:/Users/hussain.a/Desktop/newprojectpocdetails/temp (Autosaved).xls", beans, "C:/Users/hussain.a/Desktop/newprojectpocdetails/demo.xls");
```

i am setting the cell formulas such as ${employee.field1} ,${employee.field2}
and it is working properly

but in the next few columns i need some calculation on the values retrieved from the object ,
so I write

```
${employee.field1} + ${employee.field2}
// not working but results in string 1 followed by string 2
// say field1=3 , field=4 , output cell has 3+4 not 7
=sum(${employee.field1} ,${employee.field2})
// not working says error
=sum(${employee.field+employee.field2})
// not working says error
```

how to write the formulas correctly to get the desired calculation in the output xls sheet

Comment: How about number(${employee.field1}) + number(${employee.field2}) ?

Comment: the field is already number , data type is number only , though i tried it , it gives nothing